# How do I store the ENTIRE data object in Redis (not just the un-hydrated data)?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm trying to set an entire User object in my Redis store. USer has things like name and arrays of music they like.

When I set the key in redis using HSET. I notice it doesn't several part of the data set. It's unhydrated basically.

I've tried HMSET also.

Here's a code snippet of what Im doing:

````
mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function() {
  if (!this.useCache) {
    return exec.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  const key = JSON.stringify(
    Object.assign({}, this.getQuery(), {
      collection: this.mongooseCollection.name
    })
  );
  //See if we have a value for 'key' in redis
  const cacheValue = await client.hget(this.hashKey, key);

  //If we do, return that
  if (cacheValue) {
    //console.log("From cache");
    const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue);

    return Array.isArray(doc)
      ? doc.map(d => new this.model(d))
      : new this.model(doc);
  }

  //Otherwise, issue the query and store the result in redis
  const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);

  client.hset(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));

  if (this.mongooseCollection.name !== "systems") {
    client.expire(this.hashKey, 1800); // 30 minutes cache
  }

  //console.log("Saved hashkey to cache");

  return result;
};```

I would like to get the entire object back.
````

Comment: Did you consider using RedisJSON.io?

Comment: are you sure `JSON.stringify(result)` contains all of the data you want to save?

Comment: @ruhul Actually I noticed doing a console on the stringify much is missing. thanks.